# cordova : what is the use of platform_www folder?

Tags: cordova

Adding a platform in cordova creates files & folders for that platform. This includes a folder named `platform_www` for ex `ios\platform_www`, The files in this folder are available in the folder `www`.

Please explain use of this folder & why its required?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## An overview of platform_www

- Running the command `cordova platform add ios` creates the `platform_www` directory under `platforms/ios/`. This directory contains javascript files, like `cordova.js` which are added to the mobile app when it's built. At this point the `platforms/ios/www` directory doesn't exist yet.
- Every Cordova plugin contains a javascript wrapper that communicates with the native code (iOS swift/objective-c, Android Java/NDK, etc). When running the command `cordova plugin add` the `platform_www` directory is updated with a javascript wrapper file pertaining to that plugin. At this point the `platforms/ios/www` directory doesn't exist yet.
- Running `cordova build ios` is equivalent to running `cordova prepare ios` and then `cordova compile ios`. The `cordova prepare` command copies the user's `www` directory in the root directory, and combines it with `platforms\ios\platform_www` to create a new directory `platforms\ios\www`.
- Running `cordova clean` removes the `platforms\ios\www` directory, but leaves the `platforms\ios\platform_www` directory and the `www` directory in place, so they can be combined in future builds. Running `cordova plugin remove` removes the javascript wrapper file for a specific plugin from `platforms/ios/platform_www`. And running `cordova platform remove ios` will remove the `platforms/ios/platform_www` directory.

Comment: Great answer - except did you mean "platform_www" rather than "www_platforms"?

Comment: @track0 - Thanks. Yes, lol. Somehow was able to write an entire summary on a directory that doesn't exist! You're correct, the directory is "platform_www". I've updated the answer. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 6):

The `platform_www` directory is used by the Cordova CLI as a sort of 'master source' for the platform-specific JS files that ultimately go into the `www` directory. Meaning, it includes the `cordova.js`, the source files for `cordova.js`, and any plugin JS files. When you `prepare` the platform, the CLI uses `platform_www` and munges it with the other `www` content to create the platforms' `www` directory.

Comment: So should I copy everything from **platform_www** into my **www** directory?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Cordova does that automatically when you run the prepare command.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most meaningful answer will be on the source of Cordova.
This [link](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/getting-started/app-project-structure/) express every folder and directory structure.

> The directory structure contains some specially named directories that
> contain assets that are part of the build process.
>
> The special directories are:
>
> **www:** (required) this directory contains the html, javascript and other
> assets that should be included in your application. This directory
> should contain a file called index.html that is the HTML root of your
> application.
>
> **merges:** (optional) this directory can contains several
> directories named after platforms supported by PhoneGap Build
> (ios,android,winphone,windows). Content inside this directory will be
> copied over the www directory before building the app (after plugin
> installation). This directory is used for content that will change
> depending on the platform eg. a stylesheet that should only be used
> for an android build would be in merges/android/style.css.
>
> Any other sub-directories will not be packaged with the application.
> For instance your config.xml can contain references to splash screens
> and icons that are contained in a top level directory and if a file is
> not used for a splash or icon for a specific platform then it will not
> be packaged in the app.